# How to add proper margin for modal in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

Hi have following in my controller:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/selectTemplateModal.html', {
      self: self,
      animation: 'slide-in-up',
   }).then(function(modal) {
      self.modal = modal;
   });

   self.openModal = function() {
      self.modal.show();
   };

   self.closeModal = function() {
      self.modal.hide();
   };
```

And my Html and css for the modal is as below:

```
<ion-modal-view id="templateModal" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; top: 5%; left: 5%; right: 5%; bottom: 5%;">
   <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class = "title">Modal Title</h1>
   </ion-header-bar>

   <ion-content>

   </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>

<style>
.modal-backdrop-bg {
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
}

.active .modal-backdrop-bg {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
```

No matter how Much I tried to add the margins my modal doesnot come to the center.

Comment: by default the modal position is relative. You need to set the modal position:absolute in your style

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  
  $scope.modalAnimations = ['bounceIn'
                              , 'bounceInDown'
                              , 'bounceInLeft'
                              , 'bounceInRight'
                              , 'bounceInUp'
                              , 'fadeIn'
                              , 'fadeInDown'
                              , 'fadeInDownBig'
                              , 'fadeInLeft'
                              , 'fadeInLeftBig'
                              , 'fadeInRight'
                              , 'fadeInRightBig'
                              , 'fadeInUp'
                              , 'fadeInUpBig'
                              , 'flipInX'
                              , 'flipInY'
                              , 'lightSpeedIn'
                              , 'rotateIn'
                              , 'rotateInDownLeft'
                              , 'rotateInDownRight'
                              , 'rotateInUpLeft'
                              , 'rotateInUpRight'
                              , 'slideInUp'
                              , 'slideInDown'
                              , 'slideInLeft'
                              , 'slideInRight'
                              , 'zoomIn'
                              , 'zoomInDown'
                              , 'zoomInLeft'
                              , 'zoomInRight'
                              , 'zoomInUp'
                              , 'rollIn'
                              ]
  
  $scope.showModal = function(animation) {        
    console.log(animation);
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'animated ' + animation,
      hideDelay:1020
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
      $scope.modal.show();
      $scope.hideModal = function(){
        $scope.modal.hide();
        // Note that $scope.$on('destroy') isn't called in new ionic builds where cache is used
        // It is important to remove the modal to avoid memory leaks
        $scope.modal.remove();
      }
    });
  };

});
```

```css
.animated.modal.bounceIn.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:bounceOut;
    animation-name:bounceOut;
}
.animated.modal.bounceInDown.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:bounceOutUp;
    animation-name:bounceOutUp;
}
.animated.modal.bounceInLeft.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:bounceOutLeft;
    animation-name:bounceOutLeft;
}
.animated.modal.bounceInRight.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:bounceOutRight;
    animation-name:bounceOutRight;
}
.animated.modal.bounceInUp.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:bounceOutDown;
    animation-name:bounceOutDown;
}

.animated.modal.bounceOut.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:bounceOut;
    animation-name:bounceOut;
}

.animated.modal.fadeIn.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOut;
    animation-name:fadeOut;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInDown.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutDown;
    animation-name:fadeOutDown;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInDownBig.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutDownBig;
    animation-name:fadeOutDownBig;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInLeft.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutLeft;
    animation-name:fadeOutLeft;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInLeftBig.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutLeftBig;
    animation-name:fadeOutLeftBig;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInRight.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutRight;
    animation-name:fadeOutRight;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInRightBig.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutRightBig;
    animation-name:fadeOutRightBig;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInUp.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutUp;
    animation-name:fadeOutUp;
}
.animated.modal.fadeInUpBig.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeOutUpBig;
    animation-name:fadeOutUpBig;
}

.animated.modal.flipInX.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:flipOutX;
    animation-name:flipOutX;
}
.animated.modal.flipInY.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:flipOutY;
    animation-name:flipOutY;
}

.animated.modal.lightSpeedIn.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:lightSpeedOut;
    animation-name:lightSpeedOut;
}

.animated.modal.rotateIn.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:rotateOut;
    animation-name:rotateOut;
}
.animated.modal.rotateInDownLeft.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:rotateOutDownLeft;
    animation-name:rotateOutDownLeft;
}
.animated.modal.rotateInDownRight.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:rotateOutDownRight;
    animation-name:rotateOutDownRight;
}
.animated.modal.rotateInUpLeft.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:rotateOutUpLeft;
    animation-name:rotateOutUpLeft;
}
.animated.modal.rotateInUpRight.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:rotateOutUpRight;
    animation-name:rotateOutUpRight;
}

.animated.modal.slideInUp.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:slideOutDown;
    animation-name:slideOutDown;
}
.animated.modal.slideInDown.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:slideOutUp;
    animation-name:slideOutUp;
}
.animated.modal.slideInLeft.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:slideOutLeft;
    animation-name:slideOutLeft;
}
.animated.modal.slideInRight.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:slideOutRight;
    animation-name:slideOutRight;
}

.animated.modal.zoomIn.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:zoomOut;
    animation-name:zoomOut;
}
.animated.modal.zoomInDown.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:zoomOutDown;
    animation-name:zoomOutDown;
}
.animated.modal.zoomInLeft.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:zoomOutLeft;
    animation-name:zoomOutLeft;
}
.animated.modal.zoomInRight.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:zoomOutRight;
    animation-name:zoomOutRight;
}
.animated.modal.zoomInUp.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:zoomOutUp;
    animation-name:zoomOutUp;
}

.animated.modal.rollIn.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name:rollOut;
    animation-name:rollOut;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> 
    
    <title>Ionic Modal</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Animate Modals</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="https://github.com/kevincobain2000/ionic-animated-modal" class="button button-icon ion-social-github">
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="modalAnimation in modalAnimations" ng-click="showModal(modalAnimation)">
          {{modalAnimation}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
    <script id="templates/modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">Animate Css Modals</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <div class="list">
            <h3>How it works?</h3>

            <a href="https://github.com/kevincobain2000/ionic-animated-modal" title="">
              README https://github.com/kevincobain2000/ionic-animated-modal
            </a>
            <p>
              <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="hideModal()">CLOSE</button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```